# Looping through a variable with newlines without a sub shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to loop over a variable which contains newlines in a POSIX compatible way.

The following works:

```
echo "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE" | while IFS= read -r line ; do
  echo "$line"
done
```

but the piping spawns another shell.

I then tried:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS='
'
for line in "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"; do
  echo "$line"
done
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

But it just prints the content of `"$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"`

I also tried:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
  echo "$line"
done <<< "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"
```

but also here it does not work.

Example:

```
echo "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"
echo "---"
while IFS= read -r line ; do echo "$line"; done <<< "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"
```

generates:

```
uuu
iii
Digital Signature
---
uuuniiinDigital Signature
```

or

```
00000000  75 75 75 0a 69 69 69 0a  44 69 67 69 74 61 6c 20  |uuu.iii.Digital |
00000010  53 69 67 6e 61 74 75 72  65 0a 2d 2d 2d 0a 31 20  |Signature.---.1 |
00000020  75 75 75 6e 69 69 69 6e  44 69 67 69 74 61 6c 20  |uuuniiinDigital |
00000030  53 69 67 6e 61 74 75 72  65 0a 75 75 75 0a 69 69  |Signature.uuu.ii|
00000040  69 0a 44 69 67 69 74 61  6c 20 53 69 67 6e 61 74  |i.Digital Signat|
00000050  75 72 65 0a                                       |ure.|
00000054
```

Any idea?

Comment: The code `while ... do ... done <<< "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"` works for me. What problem do you have?

Comment: @bodo I get just one loop iteration. macOS with bash 5.1.16(1)-release (I added the example to the question)

Comment: I successfully tested it with Git Bash on Windows and bash on Linux (armv7l, Raspberry PI). How do you set the value of `REQUIRE_PURPOSE`? Can you add code that sets the variable? Did you intentionally use `read -a` instead of `read -r` in the code below "Example:"?

Comment: Does your variable contain a sequence of ```\``` and `n` instead of real linefeed characters?

Comment: @Bodo: according to hexdump is ```0a``` (nl)

Comment: To me it is not clear if the `\n` could be the result of the processing by `echo`. The `n` before and after `iii` is suspicious. Try `printf "%s\n---\n" "$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"` and `printf "line %s\n" "$line"` instead of the `echo` commands. (I added the literal `line` to be sure it really prints one line per iteration.) I suggest to show a [mre] that sets the variable `REQUIRE_PURPOSE` and reproduces the problem in your environment.

Comment: @Bodo. Thanks! It's the result of the echo.

Comment: `xargs` by default would turn `\n` into just `n`. So would just dropping `foo\nvar` on the shell command line without any quotes. Or using `read` without the `-r`. But `echo` shouldn't do that, even if it's of the backslash-processing sort. So, I wonder what's going on with that last code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The option to `read` you need is `-a`. It will parse the input by `IFS` into the array:

```
read -a lines <<<"$REQUIRE_PURPOSE"
for i in "${lines[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Is there a POSIX compatible way?

Comment: ITYM `IFS=$'\n' read -a arr -d '' <<< "$var"`, since you need to have the `-d` separator distinct from the `IFS` separator. Though you'd probably be better off using `readarray`/`mapfile` there, just `mapfile -t arr <<< "$var"` would do.

Comment: @Matteo, `<<<` already isn't standard. Also note that it adds a trailing newline, so you might get an extra one at the end.